# Pandas DataFrame: Fill NA values based on group mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to update the NA values of a Pandas DataFrame column with the values in a groupby object.

Let's illustrate with an example:

We have the following DataFrame columns:

```
|--------|-------|-----|-------------|
| row_id | Month | Day | Temperature |
|--------|-------|-----|-------------|
| 1      | 1     | 1   | 14.3        |
| 2      | 1     | 1   | 14.8        |
| 3      | 1     | 2   | 13.1        |
|--------|-------|-----|-------------|
```

We're simply measuring temperature multiple times a day for many months. Now, let's assume that for some of our records, the temperature reading failed and we have a `NA`.

```
|--------|-------|-----|-------------|
| row_id | Month | Day | Temperature |
|--------|-------|-----|-------------|
| 1      | 1     | 1   | 14.3        |
| 2      | 1     | 1   | 14.8        |
| 3      | 1     | 2   | 13.1        |
| 4      | 1     | 2   | NA          |
| 5      | 1     | 3   | 14.8        |
| 6      | 1     | 4   | NA          |
|--------|-------|-----|-------------|
```

We could just use panda's `.fillna()`, however we want to be a little more sophisticated. Since there are multiple readings per day (there could be 100's per day), we'd like to take the daily average and use that as our fill value.

we can get the daily averages with a simple groupby:

`avg_temp_by_month_day = df.groupby(['month'])['day'].mean()`

Which gives us the means for each day by month. The question is, how best to fill the NA values with the groupby values?

We could use an `apply()`,

```
df['temperature'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: avg_temp_by_month_day.loc[r['month'], r['day']] if pd.isna(r['temperature']) else r['temperature'], 
    axis=1
)
```

however this is really slow (1M+ records).

Is there a vectorized approach, perhaps using `np.where()`, or maybe creating another Series and merging.

What's the a more efficient way to perform this operation?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm also looking at using `df.update()` - but I'm not sure how to align the groupby object yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the *fastest*, however instead of taking ~1 hour for `apply`, it takes ~20 sec for +1M records. The below code has been updated to work on 1 or many columns.

```
local_avg_cols = ['temperature'] # can work with multiple columns

# Create groupby's to get local averages
local_averages = df.groupby(['month', 'day'])[local_avg_cols].mean()

# Convert to DataFrame and prepare for merge
local_averages = pd.DataFrame(local_averages, columns=local_avg_cols).reset_index()

# Merge into original dataframe
df = df.merge(local_averages, on=['month', 'day'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_avg'))

# Now overwrite na values with values from new '_avg' col
for col in local_avg_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].mask(df[col].isna(), df[col+'_avg'])
    
# Drop new avg cols
df = df.drop(columns=[col+'_avg' for col in local_avg_cols])
```

If anyone finds a more efficient way to do this, (efficient in processing time, or in just readability), I'll unmark this answer and mark yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what speeds down your process are two things. First, you don't need to convert your groupby to a dataframe. Second, you don't need the for loop.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import nan

# Populating the dataset
df = {"Month": [1] * 6,
      "Day": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
      "Temperature": [14.3, 14.8, 13.1, nan, 14.8, nan]}

# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=df.keys())
local_averages = df.groupby(['Month', 'Day'])['Temperature'].mean()
df = df.merge(local_averages, on=['Month', 'Day'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_avg'))
# Filling the missing values of the Temperature column with what is available in Temperature_avg
df.Temperature.fillna(df.Temperature_avg, inplace=True)
df.drop(columns="Temperature_avg", inplace=True)
```

Groupby is a resource heavy process so make the most out of it when you use it. Furthermore, as you already know loops are not a good idea when it comes to dataframes. Additionally, if you have a large data you may want to avoid creating extra variables from it. I may put the groupby into the merge if my data has 1m rows and many columns.